# Visual Studio Code not recognizing file changes

Tags: visual-studio

I've just recently run into this problem. First off my I'm using rails and generate a migration my file explorer will not update until I reload the window - which in turn closes out my open files and terminals. Also when using the rails console reload! will not update my changes. It will continue working as if I never reloaded. These problems just arose a few days ago as everything was working fine before. I can't think of any changes I made between the time it was working and now. I'm running Ubuntu and any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Pretty sure any changes to the db require you to exit out of the console. As for VsCode, there is a refresh button at the top of your file tree